# PHP - what's wrong with this piece of code?

Tags: php

```
<?

function foo($return = false) {
    $x = '12345';

    $return ?
    return $x : // here it fails
    echo $x;
}

echo foo(true);

?>
```

It says "**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in...**"

**Why!?** :)

Comment: What do you mean by writing $return ? ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: @SachinIngale That's a short way of writing `$return == true ?`

Comment: `?:` is an operator. It is not the equivalent of an `if else` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use inline ifs in this way. They are normally used like this:

`echo ($return ? x : "false");`

Your code should be like this:

```
<?

function foo($return = false) {
    $x = '12345';

    if($return)
    {
        return $x
    }
    else
    {
        echo $x;
    }
}

echo foo(true);

?>
```

(more confusing for some), you don't need to add the `else` statement, as if the `if` statement is satisfied, it will return a value, thus exiting the function, which means if the `if` statement is not satisfied, it will go to the `echo` anyway:

```
<?

function foo($return = false) {
    $x = '12345';

    if($return)
    {
        return $x
    }
    echo $x;
}

echo foo(true);

?>
```

Comment: Inline ifs are called ternary operators btw. You also don't need the else part of the if, you can just do `if($return) { return $x; } echo $x;`

Comment: Can you please explain what is the difference? Regular if works great but why inline if doesn't?

Comment: @daryqsyro because a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) is not the same as an if statement. You use ternary operators to return one value or another. Using the return from function in one breaks the ternary operator.

Comment: @Styphon - I was contemplating whether to add `if($return) { return $x; } echo $x;` but I thought it would be less confusing for some people if I wrote it like I did.

Comment: @user3476093 Fair enough.

Comment: @Styphon - I have now added the function without an `else` statement aswell

Answer (score 0):

You can use the print function instead of echo:

```
<?php
function foo($return = false) {
    $x = '12345';

    return $return ? $x : print($x);
}

$x = foo(true);
```

More elegant is Styphons way from the comments:

```
if ($return) { return $x; } echo $x;
```

Comment: Yes, it will return $x OR return 1 AND print $x.